# Equivalent of vb.net 'Except' method in Java

Tags: java, vb.net

I want to do exactly like this in java

[Compare two string ArrayLists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885700/compare-two-string-arraylists)

the accepted answer is perfect.. 'Except' method... is there a equivalent of this in Java ...
sure there isn't in standard Java lib, but is there something in third party libs like apache ?

P.S I googled this .. coudn't find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the elements of list `a` that are not present in list `b`.

How about:

```
a.removeAll(b);
```

That will remove all elements of `b` from `a`.  Whatever's left in `a` is by definition something that wasn't in `b`.

If you can't or don't want to change `a`, copy it and do the `removeAll()` on the copy.

And more generally, if your collection class in Java doesn't support `removeAll()`, then create a collection type that does support it from `a` and do the remove on that new object.

If the lists are large, you'll probably want to create a `HashSet` from `a` for example, so the removals (i.e. the internal lookup part of doing a removal) can happen more efficiently than for a `List` subtype.